# Is there an R function finding a vector within another vector?

Tags: r, vector, position, match

For example, I have two vectors:

```
x1 <- c(0,1,2)
x2 <- c(1,2,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,0,1,2)
```

I would like to find the position where x1 is first present x2, which is in this case is 3.
I have tried `which()`, `match()`, but both seems to find elements, instead of vectors. Is there a R function that can achieve this or a way to construct one?

Thank you!

Comment: are you looking for `match(x1[1],x2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to do rolling comparison.

```
x1 <- c(0,1,2) 
x2 <- c(1,2,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,0,1,2)

which(zoo::rollapply(x2, length(x1), function(x) all(x == x1)))
#[1]  3 11
```

To get the 1st occurrence -

```
which(zoo::rollapply(x2, length(x1), function(x) all(x == x1)))[1]
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was very helpful as well!!

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the first match of `0`:

```
match(x1[1], x2)
```

But for the whole vector:

```
> which(apply(t(embed(x2, length(x1))) == rev(x1), 2, all))[1]
[1] 3
>
```

**Edit:**

To give `NA` on no-match:

```
cond <- apply(t(embed(x2, length(x1))) == rev(x1), 2, all)
if (any(cond)) which(cond)[1] else NA
```

### Explanation:

This uses `embed` to split `x2` into chunks by the length of `x1`, and it applies it and detects whether it is equivalent to `x1`, and gives a boolean vector (or `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s). Then finally it uses `which` to get the index of the occurrences of `TRUE`, and I use `[1]` to get the first value.

For the edit, I detect if in the conditioned boolean vector contains any `TRUE`s, if so, do the same thing as mentioned above, if not, give `NA`.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is very helpful. I am looking for the whole vector. Follow up question: is there a way for it to return NA if the whole vector is not present in x2?

Comment: @Zofhd Check my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

For all elements for vector x1.

```
sapply(x1, function(x) match(x,x2))
[1] 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `stringr`;

```
   library(tidyverse)

x1_ <- paste0(x1,collapse="")
x2_ <- paste0(x2,collapse="")
str_locate_all(x2_, x1_)[[1]]
```

gives,

```
     start end
[1,]     3   5
[2,]    11  13
```

which returns empty if there is no match.